# UITableView with Search Bar Issue

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have a UITableView that has a Search Bar. Everything works fine but when I scroll to the bottom of the table I can still scroll up and it hides the search bar as well as duplicates the cells (as if I am scrolling through them twice).

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You placed the searchbar in tableview header.

Place it above the table